# How to add a tf.constant to the outputs in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a running model, build with :

`model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layers, outputs=outputs)`

If I try to add a simple constant to the outputs, I get an error message.
ex:

```
output = output + [tf.constant(['label1', 'label2'], dtype = tf.string)]
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layers, outputs=outputs)
```

error message : `AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.`

Is there a way to add it to the model, even if after training or at the save() time.

The idea is to have the constant as an output during serving time.

example of a full network with the errror:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
hidden = keras.layers.Dense(10)(input)
output = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(hidden)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[output, tf.constant(['out1','out2','out3'], dtype=tf.string)])
```

error

```
in <module>
      5 hidden = keras.layers.Dense(10)(input)
      6 output = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(input)
----> 7 model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[output, tf.constant(['out1','out2','out3'], dtype=tf.string)])

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    144 
    145   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 146     super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    147     _keras_api_gauge.get_cell('model').set(True)
    148     # initializing _distribution_strategy here since it is possible to call

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    165         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
    166       # Graph network
--> 167       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
    168     else:
    169       # Subclassed network

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    268 
    269     if any(not hasattr(tensor, '_keras_history') for tensor in self.outputs):
--> 270       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
    271 
    272     self._base_init(name=name, **kwargs)

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in create_keras_history(tensors)
    182     keras_tensors: The Tensors found that came from a Keras Layer.
    183   """
--> 184   _, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, set(), [])
    185   return created_layers
    186 

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, processed_ops, created_layers)
    208     if getattr(tensor, '_keras_history', None) is not None:
    209       continue
--> 210     op = tensor.op  # The Op that created this Tensor.
    211     if op not in processed_ops:
    212       # Recursively set `_keras_history`.

/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in op(self)
   1078   def op(self):
   1079     raise AttributeError(
-> 1080         "Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.")
   1081 
   1082   @property

AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.
```

using Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 2.0

Comment: Please add full error trace, along with relevant parts of code.

Comment: What's the purpose of adding a Tensor of `tf.string` type to the model output?

Comment: I have added a simpel network and the full stacktrace. 
The purpose is to have a constant output tensor, to know what are the labels being handled by the model, not just the probabilities output. Was doing it with Estimators on TF 1.X

Comment: I have tried also with Lambda layer, `keras.background.constant()` and add the tensor to model.outputs at the end of training, and saving. All give an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the constant inside a Lambda layer. Keras does some extra book keeping so you need more than just tf operations for things to work. Using a Lambda layer will do this for you.

Edit to give an example of how this works:
Your last example would translate to the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
hidden = keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
output1 = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(hidden)

@tf.function
def const(tensor):
    batch_size = tf.shape(tensor)[0]
    constant = tf.constant(['out1','out2','out3'], dtype=tf.string)
    constant = tf.expand_dims(constant, axis=0)
    return tf.broadcast_to(constant, shape=(batch_size, 3))

output2 = keras.layers.Lambda(const)(inputs)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output1, output2])
```

Edit: This reminded me of a project I had a while back where I had to use a lot of constants in a Keras model. Back then I wrote a layer for it

```
class ConstantOnBatch(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, constant, *args, **kwargs):
        self._initial_constant = copy.deepcopy(constant)
        self.constant = K.constant(constant)
        self.out_shape = self.constant.shape.as_list()
        self.constant = tf.reshape(self.constant, [1]+self.out_shape)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        output_shape = [batch_size]+self.out_shape
        return tf.broadcast_to(self.constant, output_shape)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        input_shape = input_shape.as_list()
        return [input_shape[0]]+self.out_shape

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        base_config['constant'] = self._initial_constant

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)
```

It might need some updating to tf2 and the code could definitely be written in a better way, but if you need a lot of constants this might provide a basis for a slightly more elegant solution than using a ton of Lambda layers.

Comment: Lambda gives the same error : `AttributeError: 'Lambda' object has no attribute 'op'``
as does using the keras.backgroud.constant() function for the tensor.

Comment: There was a bug on not using the hidden layer for the output. Otherwise all good. It runs. 
As for `input`, it is the singular form of inputs, and being that there is only one...

Comment: I think I accidentally pressed some keys while copying your code for testing and didn't remove all of them. In any case, did the solution above solve your problem? Or are you getting more error messages?

Comment: Hi there. Yes, the solution is working well. Thank you.
I was missing the point that even the lambda needed to have an input, or otherwise would not work. Not fan of the solution, but it works and that is the important.

Comment: This kind of fails when you go train. Keras requires a value to "train".
One option to solve is use the infro from here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785433/keras-training-only-specific-outputs

Comment: @Karudoso That's one way to do it, but it's probably easier to just specify the losses for the various output layers using a dictionary. In this case you only have to specify the loss for your output1 layer (which is done using the name of the tensor instead of the name of the python variable).